# C++20 - Call function declared as auto in template

Tags: c++, node.js, c++20

I'm building a nodejs addon in C++ and I am trying to make a function exporter from C++ to node. More exactly, I'm trying to build a functionality similar to this:

```cpp
std::string func(std::string param)
{
  return param;
}

void func_wrapper(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args)
{
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    std::string str(*v8::String::Utf8Value(isolate, args[0]));
    auto ret = func(str).c_str();

    args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(
        isolate, ret, NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked()); 
}

void Initialize(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports) 
{
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "func", func_wrapper);
}

NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize)
```

I am trying to make it easier to export more functions without having to create wrappers by hand, like this:

```cpp
template<auto Func>
void Export(const v8::Local<v8::Object>& exports, std::string name)
{
    auto wrapper = [](const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
        Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
        unsigned int lg = args.Length();

        auto ret = Func(args[0], args[1], ...) //how to?
    };
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, name.c_str(), wrapper);
}

std::string func(std::string param)
{
  return param;
}

void Initialize(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports) 
{
  Export<func>(exports, "func");
}

NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize)
```

But I can't figure out how to call Func in my Export function. Is there any way to give arguments to a function, one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Includes:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <string>
```

Conversion functions:

```
decltype(auto) Convert(v8::Isolate* isolate, const v8::Local<v8::Value>& value,
                       std::type_identity<std::string>)
{
    return *v8::String::Utf8Value(isolate, value);
}

template <std::integral T>
decltype(auto) Convert(v8::Isolate* isolate, const v8::Local<v8::Value>& value,
                       std::type_identity<T>)
{
    return v8::Integer::Cast(*value)->Value();
}
```

Call delegate:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
auto Call(v8::Isolate* isolate, std::function<R(Args...)> f,
          const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) <= v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>::kArgsLength);
    return [&] <std::size_t... Is> (std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return f(Convert(isolate, args[Is],
                         std::type_identity<std::remove_cvref_t<Args>>{})...);
    }(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}
```

Export function:

```
template <auto Func>
void Export(const v8::Local<v8::Object>& exports, const std::string& name)
{
    auto wrapper = [](const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
        v8::Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
        unsigned int lg = args.Length();
        auto ret = Call(isolate, std::function{ Func }, args);
    };
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, name.c_str(), wrapper);
}
```

Comment: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments (Line 11) https://pastebin.com/vAqt3FGf

Comment: @MihaiPreda Now? Are all arguments always `std::string`?

Comment: nope, there is the exactly same error. No, the arguments are not always std::string but there is a limited number of types (string, int and double I think), so making it work for one of them is good enough.

Comment: I edited the code (from the first answer) a little so now the function takes as parameter exactly the type of args[i]. This code compiles: https://pastebin.com/gRyEXmH6  (see line 25)

Comment: It worked, thank you for your help. It works for both strings and doubles now, this is how I implemented it if anyone is interested: https://pastebin.com/gRkPTTtC